# usign foreign model in own viewhelper as argument

Tags: typo3, view-helpers

From fluid, I call my viewhelper-class
<ext:thehelper adr="{adr}" />
{adr} is an array of tt_address → FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address

in the viewhelper I register the argument

```
    use FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address;
    public function initializeArguments() {
        $this->registerArgument('adr', 'FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address', 'the addresses', true);
    }
```

this fails with this message:
The argument "adr" was registered with type "FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address", but is of type "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult" in view helper

How can I receive the adr-array to work with.
Thank You for your help!

Comment: in the controller you can pass address as array to the view: `$this->view->assign('adr', $address->toArray());`.

Comment: I try this without controller. Just a viewhelper and tt_address templating. I tryed to adopt the help with "use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult;" , Bad try. what class I am missing?

Comment: then you've to accept `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult` as argument in the viewhelper:  `$this->registerArgument('adr', 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult', 'the addresses', true);
    }`

Comment: You can convert the object to an array then afterwards if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VH must accept multiple addresses then your ViewHelper argument must not register the class name of whichever object is contained within a query result, as data type.

Instead you must register the argument with type `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult`.